# Find file size in c

Tags: c, file, size

I am trying to do a protocol in c. It has to know the file size to pass it into a protocol which goes between client and server. This is the way I did it.

```
B32U file_size(FILE * file) {
    assert(file != NULL);
    B32U old = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    B32U size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file,old,SEEK_SET);
    return (size);
}
```

Does anybody know a better way in order to do that?
Since know thans

Comment: Is not that good?

Comment: You can use OS dependant function if you doesn't care about portability. Like "stat" for Unix.

Comment: those do not work on linux?

Comment: I saw that function. It is really amaizing. Thanks for the sugestion. It gives the complete file reference

Comment: Also, your function is not really friendly, since it rewind the file descriptor without even care about the original  position indicator's stream.
You should make a ftell first, then go to end, getting size and going again at the same position at the beginning of the function.

Comment: are you saying do a backup from the old position?

Comment: I updated the stuff, see if it is the right way to do the thing?

Comment: Yes, it's better. Personnaly, I would transform the "if (file)" into an assert and say in the doc that the function should take a valid pointer FILE.
Also, you don't check if your function call (like fseek, ftell) doesn't fail. So, even if it has 99,9999% probability to succed, when the 0,0001% strike, you will be clueless on what happening. Given that in the worst case scenario you can't move back the position indicator stream at his original position, then you can't salvage your program, but a error detection + log will be helpfull to not waste time chasing a 0,0001% probability error.